# How to do a search functionality over array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects

```
let falsyData = [
    {'hola': 'greet'},
    {'Travel': 'traveling'},
    {'Heart': 'corazon'},
    {'Earth': 'tierra'},
    {'Hills': 'a name'},
    {'Blackjack': 'game'},
    {'Casino': 'gambling'}
  ];
```

the functions I've made so far, are searching but it gets only the properties without the attributes. To explain better, if I type `h` in the search bar, the return data is:

`hola`, `Heart`, `Earth`, `Hills`, because are the objects containing the letter `h`, and it is OK to return the properties, but also I want to see the attributes of that properties.

here are the functions for the search functionality

```
  _matchPeople = (input) => {
    let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return falsyData.map(function(person) {
      for (let key in person) {
        if (key.match(reg)) {          
          return key;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  _changeInput = (val) => {
    let autoCompleteResult = this._matchPeople(this.state.value);    
    if (autoCompleteResult.length) {
      this.setState({result: autoCompleteResult.join(' ')});
    };
  }

  _onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

and I am rendering it here

```
  render () {
    let searchRes = this._matchPeople(this.state.value),
        match = searchRes.map(function(item) {
          return <Column><Paper><p style={searchOutput}>{item}</p></Paper></Column>;
        });
    return (
      <Grid>
         <TextField onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                    onKeyUp={this._changeInput.bind(this)} value={this.state.value} />
            {!!this.state.value.length &&
              <Row>
                {match}                
              </Row>
            }
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

I am using ReactJS, just in case.

what should I do ?

**EDIT**

to be more specific [image]

there is the image search for the letter `h`, I want something like,

```
hola //and then below I want to render greet because {'hola','greet'}

greet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to filter out array elements that don't have a key matching the expression, like this:

```
  _matchPeople = (input) => {
    let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return falsyData.filter(function(person) {
      var arr = Object.keys(person);
      return arr.some(function(key){
          if(key.match(reg)){
             return true;
          } else {
             return false;
          }
      });
    });
  }
```

_matchPeople will now get you an Array of objects which keys matches the input value. For example, `h` will not longer give you: `['hola', 'Heart', 'Earth', 'Hills']` but:

```
[
    {'hola': 'greet'},
    {'Heart': 'corazon'},
    {'Earth': 'tierra'},
    {'Hills': 'a name'},
  ];
```

It's up to you to display the object properties in your HTML however you want it.

I recommend a different structure than what you have now. Instead of having:

```
let falsyData = [
    {'hola': 'greet'},
    {'Travel': 'traveling'},
    {'Heart': 'corazon'},
    {'Earth': 'tierra'},
    {'Hills': 'a name'},
    {'Blackjack': 'game'},
    {'Casino': 'gambling'}
  ];
```

Do:

```
let falsyData = {
    'hola': 'greet',
    'Travel': 'traveling',
    'Heart': 'corazon',
    'Earth': 'tierra',
    'Hills': 'a name',
    'Blackjack': 'game',
    'Casino': 'gambling'
  };
```

The algorithm will change a little:

```
  _matchPeople = (input) => {
    let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    let filteredObj = { };
    Object.keys(falsyData).forEach(function(key) {
        if(key.match(reg)){
           filteredObj[key] = falsyData[key];
        }
    });
    return filteredObj;
  }
```

Now you'll get an object with the properties which keys do match your criteria. Instead of having an array with objects of 1 single property.

In your render function you'll have to change it like this:

```
let searchRes = this._matchPeople(this.state.value),
        match = Object.keys(searchRes).map(function(key) {
          return <Column><Paper><p style={searchOutput}>{key}</p></Paper></Column>;
        });
```

`searchRes[key]` will hold the property value. `key` will hold the property name.

Comment: explain me a little how you would render that in an html with React, as I am doing this  `let searchRes = this._matchPeople(this.state.value),
        match = searchRes.map(function(item) {
          return <Column><Paper><p style={searchOutput}>{item}</p></Paper></Column>;
        });` is a little confuse for me. Sorry I am just a beginner

Comment: `item` in this case would be an object. If your objects inside the array only have one key you could do: `var key = Object.keys(item)[0];` To print the attribute you would do `item[key]` and to print the key `key`.

Comment: A better object structure would have make this easier. Using an object to hold a single property is kind of overkill. You could have all properties inside an object instead.

Comment: that data is just to test so I can change the structure. What do you recommend?

Comment: I've updated the answer with my suggestion. The only caveat i could think of, is if you have properties that are repeated. 2 `hola` for example. But you can easily fix that with an array at the property.

Comment: I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object.Key is not a function`

Comment: It's `Object.keys()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: great. I am getting this http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1441298378.png what should I do to render the attributes of each property ? In `hola` I need to render also `greet` because `"hola": "greet"` so I want to render `hola` and below the info regarding `hola` which is `greet` in this case

Comment: I don't really know much about reactJS, but if you reach `key` like, `{key}` then to reach the attribute you would do `{searchRes[key]}`. Try replacing: `{key}` with: `{key} - {searchRes[key]}`

Comment: Awesome, I got it now :D